# One-Hot-Encoding for features!

Tags: machine-learning, classification, one-hot-encoding

I have a question about **One-Hot-Encoding**, something confusing me.:\

I have this sample dataset. My dataset is categorical:

| F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue | 3 | Car | Yes |
| 4 | Red | 6 | Ship | No |
| 3 | Pink | 3 | Cow | Yes |
| 9 | Black | 6 | Fish | Yes |

#### question:

Should I use the `One-Hot-Encoding` for `F2` and `F4` too?

This is clear for me, that must be used `one hot encoding` for column `Target`. But what about the Features?

If the answer is yes why and if the answer is no why?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Correct,  all categorical features should be encoded into binary digits so ML algo have more predictive power as categorised features cannot have order or magnitude ( be careful also about
multicollinearity if you use regression)

Some ML framework such as Catboost automatically encode features for you if you specify the feature index. I also like using python patsy to create input matrices

Comment: Thank u for your answer. The question is, this Encoding should be done before scaling and train_test_split?

Comment: As above, should only scale F1 and F3 - the one-hot encodings will alrady be either 0 or 1, so scaling doesn't make much sense. However, train_test_split in my mind should always be the first thing you do - if your preprocessing scales by the mean, if you don't split first, you are scaling training data by a mean "infected" with test data - which is a no-no.